# DataTable Buttons are not coming up in yii2 framework

Tags: javascript, php, button, datatables, yii2-advanced-app

Hi I'm using data table in Yii 2 framework. I followed [this link](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) and added everything in page, all js and css.
First I saved everything in a normal PHP page and run, everything is working fine in this page, all buttons are NOT coming up and download excel is also working.

But if I integrate the same page in Yii 2 framework and run it in this everything is working except file download, the BUTTONS are coming up, I re-checked  all the js and css, then also it's not working.

**This is the script code**

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
} );
 } );
</script>


 <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this not using flash?

Comment: its using flash.min.js.. And the button itself is not coming to download

Comment: I don't know it this is the issue, but I believe flash is disabled by default now in Chrome. That might be te reason? There is a html5 equivalent, https://datatables.net/reference/button/

Comment: How can i enable it? i tried that link in that also same problem..

Comment: I believe everything is mentioned in the link I just posted.

Comment: Let me know if the HTML5 equivalent works!

Comment: No buddy, i tried that its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it.
The problem was js was conflicting and i had to give the above js and css and javascript code to common files like footer.

Copy the js and css and javascript code below to footer page.

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable( {
dom: 'Bfrtip',
buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
]
} );
} );
</script>
```